# How to overwrite / override "play/stop music" key in Mac OS X with action script, cpp, ruby or python?

Tags: macos, keyboard-events

Hallo dear fellow programmers =D

I would like to overwrite / override the function of the "play/stop music" key in Mac OSX such that, when I stop the playback the volume will fade out, and when I start the playback the volume will fade in.

I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74139/how-to-fade-out-in-in-itunes) on StackOverflow. The accepted answer was a script and setting a custom shortcut. But what I am searching for is a way to gobally overwrite / override the function of the "play/stop music" key. The function combination with the fn key should still work as expected. Also if the user prefers to switch fn combination, so that F1..F12 keys are sent instead of function keys and activating special meaning by pressing fn key additionally, it should still work as expected by the user.

Thank you very much in advance ^^

edit: the solution shall be without using Objective C or Swift. I will prioritize solutions/suggestions which use action script, cpp, ruby or python.